# Using Comments in the PowerBI Embedded reprort

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

We can add comments for the Report in PowerBI service. Is there anyway that I can see those comments in my PowerBI embedded Report.
[snapshot of comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMQqU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Its not possible to view the comments in the PowerBI Embedded Report.
Comments are applicable to PowerBI service for business users.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/consumer/end-user-comment